# How to make search bar working in django?

Tags: python, html, django

I made a search bar and I want it to search the titles which is in the site. Before typing nothing appears but whenever I type one title all the titles appear. How to resolve this issue?

*index.html*

```
def index(request):
    query = request.GET.get('srh')
    if query:
        target1 = Destination.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)

        target1 = a, b= [Destination() for __ in range(2)]
            a.img = 'Article.jpg'
            b.img = 'Micro Tasks.jpeg'

            a.title = 'Article Writing'
            b.title = 'Micro Tasks'

            context = {'target1': target1}
            return render(request, 'index.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

*views.py*

```
<form class="love" method="GET" action="">
 {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="text" placeholder='Search..' name="srh" value="{{request.GET.srh}}"> <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"> Search </button>
</form>

 <div>
  {% for dest1 in target1 %}
   {% if dest1 %}
   <div>
    <a href="{{baseUrl}}/{{dest1.img}}">
      <img src="{{hiUrl}}/{{dest1.img}}" alt="" />
      <h3>{{dest1.title}}</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
   {% endif %}
  {%endfor%}
</div>
```

Comment: Will anybody answer?

Comment: you are overwriting target1 `target1 = a, b= [Destination() for __ in range(2)]`  . What are you trying to do there anyway?

Comment: I made this variable ```target1``` in order to make the page dynamic. Instead of writing the title and images source in ```index.html``` I wrote in ```views.py```. ```Destination()``` is in models.py. It is a class there.

Comment: The range which I have given is 2 because of two images and two titles in ```target1``` variable

Answer (score 0):

`objects.filter` reads from the database, but you have no objects in the database.

This should be enough:

```
def index(request):
    query = request.GET.get('srh')
    if query:
        destinations = Destination.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)

        context = {'target1': destinations}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

But of course it will not return any objects when the database is empty.

Comment: I am not getting anything from database. I just want it to be able to fetch title from ordinary page without database. I didn't created database yet. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: No, it does not make any sense to create objects like that and then filter/query it.  Just use a database (sqlite).

Answer (score -1):

.py codes:

```
def paylasimlar(request):
        keyword = request.GET.get("keyword")
        if keyword:
            paylasimlar = Makale.objects.filter(Q(baslik__contains=keyword) | Q(icerik__contains=keyword))
            return render(request, "feed.html", {"paylasimlar": paylasimlar})
```

and .html

```
     <form style="text-align: right">
      {% csrf_token %}
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="float: right">
<i class="material-icons">search</i>


</button>
   <input type="text" name="keyword" class="form-control" placeholder="Anı Ara..."  style="border-radius: 20px;float: right;width: 20%" aria-label="Search" >
```